# Has anybody successfully migrated from XWIKI ENTERPRISE 5.0-MILESTONE-2 to version 12.3?

Tags: mysql, xwiki

*java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed*

I'm seeing the error above and would appreciate some direction on the fix.
I'd also like know if anyone has been successful in a migration similar to mine?!

****** OLD SYSTEM ******
RHEL 6
Java 1.8.0
Tomcat Apache 6
MySQL 5.7
XWIKI ENTERPRISE 5.0-MILESTONE-2

****** NEW SYSTEM  ******
RHEL 7
Java 1.8.0
Tomcat Apache 8
MySQL v8.1
XWIKI ENTERPRISE 12.3

Comment: This is a big version jump. You might first try to migrate to an intermediate version like 7.4 and see if that succeeds.

Comment: Good thinking, I'll try that if I have time tomorrow and see how it goes.  Thank you.

Comment: I got all the old versions on RHEL6 running on RHEL7, so now I'll just update them incrementally.  Appreciate your response:)

Answer (score 0):

I got all the old versions on RHEL6 running on RHEL7, so now I'll just update them incrementally.